# using % with skrollr

Tags: html, css, skrollr

I have been trying to get a handle on skrollr for a few days now and it seems that I keep getting inconsistent results.
To keep this example really simple I have one section tag, that has its position fixed and a height and width of 100%

html

```
<section id='section-2' data-0="transform:translate(0,100%);" 
data-100p="transform:translate(0,0%);" data-200p="transform:translate(0,-100%);">
```

css:

```
section{
   position:fixed; 
   height:100%; 
   width:100%; 
   background-color"red"; 
   top:0; 
   left:0;
 }
```

It doesn't seem to scroll 200% of the view port. The red section scrolls up(100p), but then stops at the top of the viewport and nothing else to scroll.

Comment: What you've posted does exactly what it should. Please create a reproducible test page. http://jsbin.com/degobovi/1

Comment: Thanks! I figured out my issue.